# firebase realtime db get non existent child throws exception

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

my code is like

```
 var db = admin.database();
 var ref = db.ref('referrals')

 ref.child("ABCD").once("value").then(
                (resp) => { }
  ).catch(err => console.error("error"))
```

if referrals do not have child node "ABCD" it goes to exception block. How can i check the existence of it and handle rather throwing to catch?

Answer (score 0):

Try ;

```
 var db = admin.database();
 var ref = db.ref('referrals')

 ref.child("ABCD").once("value", resp => { 
     if (resp.exists()) {
       // Data exists 
     }else {
       // No data fetched
     }
```

})